# Не выводится кол-во повторений в массиве

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{   srand(time(NULL));
    int  i, n, k, kol = 0;
    cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    float mass[n], max, min;
    cout << "Элементы: ";
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = rand()%60-20;
        cout << mass[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    min = mass[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(min > mass[i])
            {
                min = mass[i];
                k = i;
            }
    }
    cout << "Номер Min: " << k << endl;
    cout << "Значение Min: " << min << endl;
    if (mass[i] = min) kol++ ; // Не могу вывести кол-во повторяющихся элементов

}
```

Comment: Последняя строка кода, чудесная сама по себе, не отвечает на вопрос, что собственно нужно и в каком виде? Количество элементов в массиве, равных min?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сможете создать статический массив, используя в качестве его длины переменное выражение `n`. Замените строку `float mass[n];` на `float* mass = new float[n];` и в конце программы удалите выделенную под массив память: `delete[] mass;`

По поводу переменной `kol`. Как я понял, вам нужно найти количество элементов, равных `min`. Вам нужно использовать цикл при нахождении `kol`. Замените `if (mass[i] = min) kol++;` на

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (mass[i] == min) kol++; 
}
cout << "Значение kol: " << kol << endl;
```